# kinect v1 no output although the drivers are installed correctly

Tags: processing, kinect, openkinect

a Kinect-Noob here.

My machine runs Windows 10 - x86

I connected my kinect v1 to computer after installing kinect runtime, kinect for windows drivers, SDKs and developer toolkit. It wont show anything on the kinect studio even when I ran kinect enabled app - 3D scan from windows store.

[This is the screen shot of the drivers being properly installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGhMv.png)

The processing example (called Point Cloud of OpenKinect processing library) code shows error as :

```
64 windows 

There are no kinects, returning null
```

Earlier (5 weeks back) same code used to give output. During those 5 weeks, I updated windows 10.

I uninstalled and installed the whole kinect package (runtime, SDK, toolkit and drivers), but no results. Also, removed zigfu plugins (for primesense and OpenNI). Still no results

Any help is appreciated !

Thanks !!!

Comment: The first thing I would try is the simplest thing: have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: @KevinWorkman, yes. I tried doing that. Still no results. The led keeps blinking. No Kinect output.

Comment: i'm trying to solve the problem of connecting a v1 (have one laying around, don't want to buy a new one) to windows 10...  as far as i can tell the sdk (2.0) compatible with windows 10 is not compatible with the v1/360 kinect...  the highest sdk (1.8) compatible with v1 is not compatible with windows 10 (runs on windows versions 7 to 8.1)...  i'm looking into openkinect now, but it doesn't seem like the issue has been solved by the open source community either...